# Lag xts object for kmeans analysis

Tags: r, k-means, xts

I am trying to get a univariate distribution using code obtained from R-bloggers for kmeans clustering. The example the author used was the S&P 500, obtained with `getSymbols('SPY')`. I am trying to apply the code to my own data. I need to figure out:

1. How to modify the code so that it correctly reruns my data, as some inputs by the creator need to be altered, I think.
2. I need to know why it is only lagging the data by 1 day (see below), since my data is monthly and need the lag to change according to my data.

What I see that the code does is lags the data by one period. The author's code used daily S&P data, but my data is monthly. The problem I run into is that by using the author's code, it is lagging my data by one day rather than one month. I have been trying to understand the code better, but I cannot see where to modify the code so that it lags 1 month.

My data:

```
           Composite
2006-07-31     -3.35
2006-08-31      3.46
2006-09-30      3.80
2006-10-31      4.24
2006-11-30      2.97
2006-12-31     -0.33
```

The following is the code, which I slightly modified to omit nas:

```
###################if you want uniform distribution - uncomment the following lines##############
rez=na.omit(apply(
(nasa),2,function(x){
y=(xts(x,order.by=as.POSIXct(as.Date(attr(x,'names')))))

print(xts(rollapply(y,20,function(z){which(order(z)==20)/20},align='right')))
}))
nasa=xts(rez,order.by=as.POSIXct(tail(index(nasa),-19)))
colnames(nasa)=c('Percent of High')
```

Original code:

https://github.com/kafka399/Rproject/blob/master/kmeans/kmeans.R

Comment: That code is atrocious. I can't even begin to guess at what it's supposed to do. What's wrong with simply using `?lag`?

Comment: So all that can be replaced by: `x <- rollapplyr(nasa, 20, function(z) which(order(z)==20)/20, by.column=TRUE)` or, in your case (since you only have one column): `x <- rollapplyr(nasa, 20, function(z) which(order(z)==20)/20)`. What's wrong with that?